# Как с помощью inline кнопок в telebot(pytelegrambotapi) вызывать обработчик команды?

Tags: python, telebot

И в идеале не давать пользователю перейти к определенным действиям, пока он не сделает другие?

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_handler(call):
    # match call.data:
    #     case 1:
    #         bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, register_user)
    print(call)

    if call.data == 1:
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, register_user)
        return

    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретизируйте ваш вопрос, ибо понять, что вы хотите, сложно, но вот вам как нужно делать инлайн кнопки и обрабатывать их.

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

import config

bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(msg: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка 1", callback_data="but_1"))
    bot.send_message(chat_id=msg.chat.id, text="Жми кнопку", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "but_1")
def but1_pressed(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Вы нажали кнопку")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```