# Как вызывать call handler из message handler [telebot]

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть message handler:

```
def to_pay_handler_2(message):
    if type(int(message.text))==str:
        users[message.chat.id]['FIO']=message.text
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Извините, похоже вы ошиблись, попробуйте еще.',
                         parse_mode="Markdown")
        to_pay_handler(message)
```

В последней строчке, я пытаюсь вызвать call handler, но вылезает ошибка `'Message' object has no attribute 'message'`, я не понимаю как вызвать call функцию в message функции, так как когда я пытаюсь вызвать из call функции call функцию, то все хорошо, а когда пытаюсь из message функции в call функцию, то возникают проблемы:

```
def to_pay_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='*Для заполнения данных заказа введите необходимую информацию.*', parse_mode="Markdown")
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='Введите полное *ФИО*:',parse_mode="Markdown")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message,to_pay_handler_2)
```

Весь код:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "to_pay")
def to_pay_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    try:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='*Для заполнения данных заказа введите необходимую информацию.*', parse_mode="Markdown")
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='Введите полное *ФИО*:',parse_mode="Markdown")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message,to_pay_handler_2)
    except KeyError:
        back_to_start_handler(call.message)
def to_pay_handler_2(message):
    users[message.chat.id]['FIO']=message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введите свой *номер телефона*:', parse_mode="Markdown")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, to_pay_handler_3)
```

Comment: А шо это за проверка такая? `if type(int(message.text))==str`

Comment: @oleksandrigo Ущербная попытка проверки на то, что пользователь ввел. Например не могут быть числа в ФИО.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1429784/Как-с-помощью-inline-кнопок-в-telebotpytelegrambotapi-вызывать-обработчик-кома?rq=1 это вам не подходит?

Comment: @oleksandrigo к сожалению, там указывается обычный отклик от inline клавиатуры. Если взять ваш пример, то мне нужен переход из but1_pressed в start.

Comment: Дайте больше кода, с учётом декораторов

Comment: @oleksandrigo дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Так, а что у вас не работает? Выглядит как рабочий код, разве что убрать try/except и `back_to_start_handler(call.message)`

Comment: Опишите в деталях алгоритм того что вы хотите от бота

Comment: @oleksandrigo я хочу вызвать функцию to_pay_handler из to_pay_handler_2 , тоесть перейти из to_pay_handler, в to_pay_handler_2, но если я напишу to_pay_handler(message), то выдает ошибку.

Comment: Зачем её вызывать?

Comment: @oleksandrigo чтобы сделать кнопку выхода.